# How to format seconds to H:M:S using d3js.org

Tags: d3.js

I would like to use d3 api to convert seconds into H:M:S.
Currently doing:

```
 var parseSeconds = d3.time.format("%S").parse;
 var formatSeconds = d3.format("%H:%M:%S");
 var s = 3661;
 console.log( formatSeconds( parseSeconds(s) ) );
```

Expected result 01:01:01

I'm aware of [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com) but would like to stick to d3.

Please advise,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things; the first is that d3 is expecting a date object and you're passing in a number; and the second is that you need to use a time formatter. These issues are giving you unexpected results.

You could avoid using libraries altogether and just write a simple custom function.

Alternatively you could add the seconds to a convenient data and use a modified version of the code you've posted.

The `var formatSeconds = d3.format("%H:%M:%S");` line should read:

```
var formatSeconds = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S");
```

So using the second approach choose a time, say 01/01/2014, and create a date object by:

```
var d = new Date(2014, 4, 1);
```

Then parse to Unix Epoch time by:

```
var u = +d;
```

(See the [d3 doc's page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#_format) for further explanation)

Create your time in hours, minute and seconds by adding the number of milliseconds to `u`. E.g. To add 3661 seconds try:

```
var newU = u + (3661*1000);
```

Now, convert this back to a date object using:

```
new Date(newU)
```

And pass into your (modified) function:

```
formatSeconds(new Date(newU));
```

You could obviously iterate across an array of date, or what ever suit's your data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the solution. But there is a case when duration is longer than 86400 seconds (24 hours).

With this approach 86401 seconds will be formated as 00:00:01, the expectation is to have 24:00:01

Comment: D3 for %H has possible values [0:23] :(

Comment: Ended using a custom function:
`function format(num) {
        var h = Math.floor( num / 3600 );
        var m = Math.floor((num - h * 3600) / 60 );
        var s = num - (h * 3600 + m * 60);

        return ( h < 10 ? "0" + h : h )
            + ":" +
            ( m < 10 ? "0" + m : m )
            + ":" +
            ( s < 10 ? "0" + s : s );

}`